# The MSSQLSERVER service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have created one sample of node js . But when I start the application is going to connection of sql server then not give response by sql server.

When i going in service panel and start sql server agent then give blow error....

This service  on local computer started and then stopped. some service  stop automatically if then are not in use by other service  or programs
[image]

OR.........

When i am going in the sql server config and start of sql server agent then show error

The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log log or other application error for details.
[image]

Comment: Read. The log. SQL Server writes a lotfile, you know. It will tell you why it shuts down.

Comment: This question may be better suited for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: This [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/955494/error-message-when-you-use-sql-server-configuration-manager-to-restart) from Microsoft recognizes the issue and has a workaround.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had found the solution to this problem. I have added the TCP Port 1433 in SQL  set the TCP Port=1433

1. Configuration => Protocols for SQLEXPRESS => TCP/IP
2. Then right click and go to property

   [image]
3. After that show screen and go to Ip Address

   [image]
4. After that show screen and go to IPALL

   [image]
5. After that set the TCP Ip: 1433

   [image]
6. And click on <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>

   [image]

Comment: "I had found solution of this problem" - only if we define the problem as "I cannot get Node to connect to SQL Server" which was only mentioned in passing as the first sentence of your question. It's not a solution to the "problem" that the rest of your question related to.

Comment: awesome. this worked for me after hours of troubleshooting. upvoted.

Comment: also restart SQL Server service before trying to start SQL Server Agent.

Answer (score 3):

**Worked for me after** changing the **appropriate user and credential** for the instance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server *is* running, as shown in your screen shots:

[image: SQL Server is running]

If Node is failing to connect to it, it's probably a flaw in your connection string.

What isn't running is [SQL Server *Agent*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189237.aspx). Which is a system for running scheduled tasks in SQL Server. It is bizarrely *installed* but *not* runnable when the SQL Server instance you're dealing with is [SQL Server *Express*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx). Which, again, your screenshots confirm is the case here.

Comment: @surendraKandira - As I tried to say, SQL Server Agent *will not run* for SQL Server Express. By Design.

Answer (score 0):

In my case just needs to disable VIA protocol.

Go to Sql Server Configuration Manager-> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER then right click on VIA and select disable.

Alert me if that's it!