# Mysql installation problems. (The mysql local service started and stopped . Some services...)

Tags: mysql, installation, windows-10

I understand that this question has been asked alot of times before with and I have tried everyone of their solutions. It hasn't worked for me. To summarize I'm installing using the windows msi installer version 8.0.22.0 to install mysql. Everything goes fine in the installation until we get to the starting services part of the installation. There it gets stuck at starting server never advancing. I know that's due to the service not starting and I do the recommended step of running services.msc as a service. I'll also paste my error log that I got from the programdata/mysql/mysql server 8.0/ directory.

Important info
mysql version 8.0.22.0
using msi installer
windows 10

2020-11-08T19:46:08.681432Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2020-11-08T19:46:08.682752Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.22) starting as process 17300
2020-11-08T19:46:08.719892Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-11-08T19:46:09.221182Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-11-08T19:46:09.369387Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-11-08T19:46:09.464341Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-11-08T19:46:09.465186Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2020-11-08T19:46:09.477256Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-000001 - Can't create/write to file 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data????.pid' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
2020-11-08T19:46:09.479597Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010092] [Server] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No such file or directory
2020-11-08T19:46:09.485610Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-11-08T19:46:10.655699Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

The questions I've looked at
[the MySQL service on local computer started and then stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670755/the-mysql-service-on-local-computer-started-and-then-stopped)
[The MSSQLSERVER service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080354/the-mssqlserver-service-on-local-computer-started-and-then-stopped-some-service)

[image: my services properties]

[image: error message]

Comment: Apparently it can't write the pid file. I think it is supposed to write in directory C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data, but is seems to be missing a backslash between the directory and the pidfile. That may be just a logging bug, but to be sure: could you maybe add a backslash behind the datadir setting in your mysql.ini?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check in your my.ini which is located in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\`

> Can't create/write to file `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data????.pid`

As you can see the correct path would be

```
[mysqld]
pid-file = "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data/????.pid"
```